# Wiremock JS has problem with response templating

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, wiremock

```
{
    "request": {
        "method": "POST",
        "urlPathPattern": "/v1/customer"
    },
    "response": {
        "status": 200,
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        "bodyFileName": "data/customer-{{jsonPath request.body '$.cid'}}.json",
        "transformers": ["response-template"]
    }
}
```

- In Mac, it is working well!
- In Linux, it is giving this error:

```
<pre> Server Error</pre></p><h3>Caused by:</h3>
<pre>java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException:
 /mocks/./__files/data/customer-{{jsonPath request.body &apos;$.cid&apos;}}.json
  (No such file or directory)\n
```

Is there any solution or workaround? Appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I would advice to always run [Wiremock via Docker](https://hub.docker.com/r/rodolpheche/wiremock) to prevent issues such as "it works on my machine".

However, what works for us on all machines is the following:

```
{
   "city": "{{jsonPath request.body '$.contact[0].contactMedium[0].characteristic.city'}}",
   "postCode": "{{jsonPath request.body '$.contact[0].contactMedium[0].characteristic.postCode'}}",
   "street1": "{{jsonPath request.body '$.contact[0].contactMedium[0].characteristic.street1'}}",
   "type": "{{jsonPath request.body '$.contact[0].contactMedium[0].characteristic.type'}}",
}
```

I geuss your OS doesn't like `&apos;$.cid&apos;`.

And you need to make sure the file exists as well. For me, I always provide a default file to prevent Wiremock from breaking. And then use `priority` to override a specific request.